# AM io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1 lambda$0

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, appium, appium-android

**Issue**

I am getting an exception in eclipse when I ran the code.

**Exception:**

```
 [Mar 02, 2021 7:50:21 AM io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1 lambda$0
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils
    at io.appium.java_client.internal.ElementMap.getElementClass(ElementMap.java:77)
    at io.appium.java_client.internal.JsonToMobileElementConverter.newRemoteWebElement(JsonToMobileElementConverter.java:69)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.JsonToWebElementConverter.apply(JsonToWebElementConverter.java:55)
    at io.appium.java_client.internal.JsonToMobileElementConverter.apply(JsonToMobileElementConverter.java:63)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:561)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:41)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:323)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElement(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:61)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElement(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElement(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:428)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElementByXPath(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:151)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElementByXPath(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElementByXPath(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at irfantest.Basics.main(Basics.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 17 more][1]
```

**Question**

can you please tell me why this exceptions occurres and how to solve it?